# Adding options in MongoDB Regex Expression in Spring Data

Tags: regex, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to do automated Regex expression match with Spring MongoDB Data.
This is what I have tried, but Spring doesn't recognize the options I am giving. I am trying to give the option 'i' to make the matching case insensitive. But doesn't seem to work.

```
fun findByAddress_CityRegex(city: String, options: String) : Flux<Designer>
```

Best Regards,